# Access Value from Different reference in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm having a problem to accessing the value from different reference .
here is the code for first part .

```
   DatabaseReference databaseBazars.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            Integer mealrate = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
                Integer cost = Integer.valueOf(bazar.getCost());
                mealrate = mealrate + cost; //want to send the value of mealrate


            }




            AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMeal.this);
            dialog1.setTitle("Notification");
            dialog1.setMessage("Total Cost  : " +mealrate);
            dialog1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
            dialog1.setNeutralButton(
                    "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
            dialog1.show();

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Now i want to get the value of "mealrate" in that event(below) .by the way they are belongs to same function.how can i get the value from upper event to the lower event (dbr.addLis.....)

```
DatabaseReference dbr.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            abcd.clear();
            Integer total = 0;



            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Integer costs7=Integer.valueOf(meals2.getS2());
              total = total +cost7+ mealrate;//here i can't get the value of mealrate
                 abcd.add(meals2);


            }




        MealList adapter = new MealList(ShowMeal.this, abcd);
        sm.setAdapter(adapter);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMeal.this);
        dialog1.setTitle("Notification");



        dialog1.setMessage("Total Meal  : " +total );


        dialog1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
        dialog1.setNeutralButton(
                "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
        dialog1.show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

please help me out.

i'v tried with this way too , it's make app got crashes

```
   databaseBazars.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {




        dbr.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                Integer totala = 0;

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Bazar bazar = ds.getValue(Bazar.class);
                    Integer cost = Integer.valueOf(bazar.getCost());
                    totala = totala + cost;


                }



                abcd.clear();
                Integer total = 0;
                Integer s1=0;
                Integer s2=0;
                Integer s3=0;
                Integer s4=0;
                Integer s5=0;
                Integer s6=0;
                Integer s7=0;

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MealE meals1 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals2 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals3 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals4 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals5 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals6 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    MealE meals7 = ds.getValue(MealE.class);
                    Integer costs1 = Integer.valueOf(meals1.getS1());
                    Integer costs2=Integer.valueOf(meals2.getS2());
                    Integer costs3=Integer.valueOf(meals3.getS3());
                    Integer costs4=Integer.valueOf(meals4.getS4());
                    Integer costs5=Integer.valueOf(meals5.getS5());
                    Integer costs6=Integer.valueOf(meals6.getS6());
                    Integer costs7=Integer.valueOf(meals7.getS7());
                    s1=s1+costs1;
                    s2=s2+costs2;
                    s3=s3+costs3;
                    s4=s4+costs4;
                    s5=s5+costs5;
                    s6=s6+costs6;
                    s7=s7+costs7;

                    total = total + costs1+costs2+costs3+costs4+costs5+costs6+costs7;
                    abcd.add(meals1);

                }


                MealList adapter = new MealList(ShowMeal.this, abcd);
                sm.setAdapter(adapter);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMeal.this);
                dialog1.setTitle("Notification");



                dialog1.setMessage("Total Meal  : " +total
                        +"\n" +"\n"+"Nayeem  : " +s1
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Nizam   : " +s2
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Rabbani : " +s3
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Saikat  : " +s4
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Sagar   : " +s5
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Nayan   : " +s6
                        +"\n"+"\n"+"Touqir  : " +s7
                        +"\n"+"\n" +"\n"+"MEAL RATE :  "+totala);


                dialog1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
                dialog1.setNeutralButton(
                        "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                dialog1.show();



                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, since the listeners are for one reference at the time; what you can do is concatenate the references together and use the values there, take a look at this snippet.

```
    mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("files").child("files_"+sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_idioma), locale)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshotFiles) {

                mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("filescar").child("filescar_"+sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_idioma), locale)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotFilesCar) {


            // I do something with the two references,
            // here is your for statement

}
```

Take a look, you request data from the first Firebase reference, you get the data and store it at `mealrate`, now if you access that variable from your other reference without concatenation, you can have an updated value in your first reference and you second reference will not ask for the updated value, or even the app will crash, so, if you put your references together you can work with the two of them and not having any problem.

Comment: i can't get that . please do a sample for me with this code

Comment: databaseBazars.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() this line showing underline error

Comment: fine it's worked now . i have to make mealrate final :)

Comment: Yes, you can see in my snippet I put final on it